# How to create a multi tabbed eclipse view such that each tab consist of its own view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to create an eclipse **View** with multiple tabs such that each tab itself is a view.

To state an example we have already this `XMLEditor (XMLMultiPageEditorPart)` in eclipse in which we get two tabs `Design` and `Source`.

How can we create this kind of a multi tabbed View for an Eclipse Plugin.

Comment: XMLEditor is an editor, not a view. It is based on `MultiPageEditorPart` which supports mutli-page editors. There is no equivalent for views.

Comment: @greg-449 Yeah, I understand that it was an editor. I stated that just for an example. Basically I need to put multiple views inside a single View in such a way that we can switch between them at any given time. :)

Comment: There is no support for that. You can have tabs in a view but the tab contents won't be considered views.

Comment: Have you considered a TabFolder or CTabFolder?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the E4 model.  This is how the new *Split Editor* functionality is implemented (see *Window > Editor > Toggle Split Editor*).

Eclipse 4.x introduced a new layer, called E4, between the very opinionated Eclipse Workbench APIs (IEditorPart, IViewPart, and friends) and JFace.  By *opiniated* I mean that the Workbench APIs present a very prescriptive UI model and  policies. E4 is comparatively unopinionated and deals only with *parts*, and has no notion of *editors* vs *views*.  E4 allows embedding parts within parts.

If you go this route, the entry-points to implementation is as follows:

- the splitting is toggled by [SplitHander](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/ui/internal/SplitHandler.java?h=master) which just adds some well-defined *tags* to a particular E4 model part
- a [SplitterAddon](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/addons/splitteraddon/SplitterAddon.java?h=master) listens for such tag changes and creates or destroys the *MCompositePart* that will host the different editors.  The real meat is in the `splitPart()` method.